# I want to change AUTO_INCREMENT to UUID

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment, uuid

Ok, so I have this,

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
  `title` text,
  `content` longtext,
  `encrypt` text,
  `password` text,
  `now_time` text,
  `s_date` text,
  `views` text,
  `ip` text,
  `date` text,
  `member` text,
  `expiry` text,
  `visible` text,
  `code` longtext
);
```

I want to change AUTO_INCREMENT to a random id or UUID.
How can I do it?

Comment: You mean automatically? You'll need a trigger for it, see e.g. [MySQL - Alter table to automatically put in a UUID](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57293)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_table
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.ID = uuid();
```

Create Trigger.